# Clojure: idiomatic code for frequency map

Tags: clojure

Let's make frequency map:

```
(reduce #(update-in %1 [%2] (fnil inc 0)) {} ["a" "b" "a" "c" "c" "a"])
```

My concern is expression inside lambda `#(...)` - is it the canonical way to do it? Can I do it better/shorter?

EDIT: Another way I found:

```
(reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (inc %1 %2 0)) {} ["a" "b" "a" "c" "c" "a"])
```

Seems like very similar, what are pros/cons? Performance?

Comment: how is your second example suppose to work actually? you will recieve `clojure.lang.ArityException` because of passing 3 args to `(inc)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Clojure 1.2, there is a `frequencies` function in `clojure.core`:

```
user=> (doc frequencies)
-------------------------
clojure.core/frequencies
([coll])
  Returns a map from distinct items in coll to the number of times
  they appear.
```

Example:

```
user=> (frequencies ["a" "b" "a" "c" "c" "a"])
{"a" 3, "b" 1, "c" 2}
```

It happens to use transients and ternary `get`; see `(source frequencies)` for the code, which is as idiomatic as it gets while being highly performance-aware.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `update-in`. My way would be:

```
(defn frequencies [coll]
  (reduce (fn [m e]
              (assoc m e (inc (m e 0))))
          {} coll))
```

Update: I assumed you knew `frequencies` was in core also and this was just an exercise.

I did a guest lecture a while ago in which I explained how you can get to this solution step by step. Won't be much new for you, since you were already close to the `core` solution, but maybe it is of value to someone else reading this question. The slides are in Dutch. If you change .html to .org it's easier to get the source code:

http://michielborkent.nl/gastcollege-han-20-06-2013/gastcollege.html
http://michielborkent.nl/gastcollege-han-20-06-2013/gastcollege.org

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using only 'assoc' and recursion:

```
(defn my-frequencies-helper [freqs a-seq]
  (if (empty? a-seq)
    freqs
    (let [fst (first a-seq)
          new_set (if (contains? freqs fst)
                    (assoc freqs fst (inc (get freqs fst)))
                    (assoc freqs fst 1))]
      (my-frequencies-helper new_set (rest a-seq)))))

(defn my-frequencies [a-seq]
  (my-frequencies-helper {} a-seq))
```

> (my-frequencies [1 1 2 2 :D :D :D])
>
> => {1 2, 2 2, :D 3}
>
> (my-frequencies [:a "moi" :a "moi" "moi" :a 1])
>
> => {:a 3, "moi" 3, 1 1}